# Having Men's Tab, Women' s tab and M&W tab to separate fashion brands

Tags: navigation, mobile-application, categorization

So we have an app where we separate brands with `Mens only` tab or `Womens only` tab. In the Mens section when you click on a brand names you immediately view their products (which of course will have male only products) and vice versa for Women.

But some of the brands sell both `Mens` and `Womens` products. I was wondering if its good UX Flow to have a third tab labeled `M&W`?

**note**

Our thought process behind it was we didn't want to have repeat brand names in both Men side and Women side respectively e.g(Brand A appearing in both Men Only and Women Only side) which is why we opted to add a third tab.

Also its an IOS app

Comment: I think you'd lose a lot of sales on those brands if you didn't include them in their specific gender as well. When I go online shopping I always click right into mens, I wouldn't bother looking for M&W and if I saw it I still likely wouldn't go in it.

Answer (score 3):

**Yes, it would be bad usability approach.** Users will search clothes *by gender* and then *brands*. If you have to repeat them, so be it, even better.

## User Case

John Doe, a male user, will look for pants. He might have a brand preference, but he'll be interested basically in men's clothes. So he will click the **"Men"** tab, hopefully finding what he was looking for.

Now imagine **mixing men and women** clothes in the same taxonomy: first of all, our user John Doe will wonder:

> what is Men and Women? Transgender clothes? Unisex clothes? Something else?

even worse, he decides to click. Now he's **lost between lots of items that are of absolutely no interest for him**, making him frustrated and having to start the whole process again.

## In short

**Men** and **Women** tabs are just fine (consider **Children** if needed). **Brands are superfluous**, they come and go, but genders are static. But if you want to make it easy for users to browse by brand, simply add a search feature, preferably a [faceted search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faceted_search)